# setting date format in menubar on top of desktop

Tags: settings, format, date

How do I change format? When I open "time & date settings" I find very limited possibilities. So is there any file which sets my date format in clock shown on top of screen? The only thing I need is just change order of values (I don't want to have week-day/MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss). And second my question: is it possible to set different font colours for values in it?    for example first colour for  month and year, and second different one for hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: That MM/DD/YYYY date format sounds like the US style. Can you please open a terminal window, run the `locale` command, and let us know the output by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

With the [dconf editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dconf-tools/), set `com.canonical.indicator.datetime.time-format` to `custom` and `com.canonical.indicator.datetime.custom-time-format` to whatever format you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Unity Tweak to customize the Time fonts and everything else. But I'm not sure that its easy to Do Change the format in the natural Ubuntu settings..
So you may refer to these websites :

1. [Six Must have Unity Tweaks](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/six-must-have-ubuntu-unity-tweaks/)
2. [Change Clock Color](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1413778)
   Hope this will help you !